# Is there a way to set the recurse depth of toJson()?

Tags: groovy

This appears to be the most easy/recommended way of pretty printing an object in groovy:

```
println prettyPrint(toJson(myDumbObject))
```

But doing this I frequently hit stack overflows because of known issues with toJson() when it finds a recursive structure: https://user.groovy.codehaus.narkive.com/07vuiZZB/groovy-user-stackoverflowerror-in-jsonoutput

Is there no way to just tell toJson() to stop after X levels?

Answer (score 1):

if you have groovy 2.5+ you can do own toJson

```
import groovy.json.*
import org.apache.groovy.json.internal.CharBuf

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class MyJsonOut extends DefaultJsonGenerator {
    private int nestLimit=32
    private int nest=0
    
    MyJsonOut(JsonGenerator.Options opts = new JsonGenerator.Options()){
        super(opts)
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void writeObject(String key, Object object, CharBuf buffer) {
        nest++
        if(nest>nestLimit)object="<TOO-DEEP>"
        super.writeObject(key, object, buffer)
        nest--
    }
    
    String toPrettyJson(Object o){
        return JsonOutput.prettyPrint(this.toJson(o))
    }
}

class A{
    String name
    def ref
}

def o=new A(name:"hohoho")
o.ref=o
println new MyJsonOut().toPrettyJson(o)
```

Comment: gewwww I guess I'll mark this as the answer, but its def not the "just set the `max-depth` property" answer I was really hoping for :(. Is there a popular alternative to pretty printing objects instead maybe?